# Coupons are not being applied when entered at the checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

Woocommerce coupons created under Marketing -> Coupons are no longer being accepted at the checkout. When a user enters the coupon code and clicks "Apply voucher", the page refreshes, a loading icon briefly appears over the order summary, then nothing happens. The total amount does not change.

I've reverted back to Storefront and disabled all plugins: the problem still persists.

An error on the System Status page told me that SoapClient was not installed on my server, but I have now installed this and the problem still persists.

If required for testing, [this is the store URL](https://logwisefirewood.co.uk/) and the valid coupon code 77qk2a9y should apply a 10% discount to the whole order.

The output of my system status report is as follows:

```
`
### WordPress Environment ###

WordPress address (URL): https://logwisefirewood.co.uk
Site address (URL): https://logwisefirewood.co.uk
WC Version: 6.9.4
REST API Version: ✔ 6.9.4

WC Blocks Version: ✔ 8.3.3
Action Scheduler Version: ✔ 3.4.0
Log Directory Writable: ✔
WP Version: 6.0.2
WP Multisite: –
WP Memory Limit: 256 MB
WP Debug Mode: –
WP Cron: ✔
Language: en_GB
External object cache: –

### Server Environment ###

Server Info: Apache/2.4.54 (Ubuntu)
PHP Version: 7.4.3
PHP Post Max Size: 8 MB
PHP Time Limit: 30
PHP Max Input Vars: 1000
cURL Version: 7.69.0-DEV
OpenSSL/1.1.1f

SUHOSIN Installed: –
MySQL Version: 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
Max Upload Size: 8 MB
Default Timezone is UTC: ✔
fsockopen/cURL: ✔
SoapClient: ✔
DOMDocument: ✔
GZip: ✔
Multibyte String: ✔
Remote Post: ✔
Remote Get: ✔

### Database ###

WC Database Version: 6.9.4
WC Database Prefix: wp_
Total Database Size: 113.99MB
Database Data Size: 94.50MB
Database Index Size: 19.49MB
wp_woocommerce_sessions: Data: 2.02MB + Index: 0.08MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_api_keys: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_order_items: Data: 0.16MB + Index: 0.08MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta: Data: 1.52MB + Index: 1.89MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_tax_rates: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_tax_rate_locations: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_shipping_zones: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_shipping_zone_methods: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_payment_tokens: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_payment_tokenmeta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_log: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_actionscheduler_actions: Data: 0.34MB + Index: 0.45MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_actionscheduler_claims: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_actionscheduler_groups: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_actionscheduler_logs: Data: 0.25MB + Index: 0.20MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_commentmeta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_comments: Data: 1.52MB + Index: 0.53MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_commercekit_searches: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_commercekit_swatches_cache_count: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_commercekit_waitlist: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_commercekit_wishlist: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_commercekit_wishlist_items: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_e_events: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_e_notes: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.17MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_e_notes_users_relations: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_e_submissions: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.23MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_e_submissions_actions_log: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_e_submissions_values: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_ewwwio_images: Data: 4.52MB + Index: 5.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_ewwwio_queue: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_layerslider: Data: 1.50MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_layerslider_drafts: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_layerslider_revisions: Data: 11.52MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_links: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_mailchimp_carts: Data: 0.05MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_mailchimp_jobs: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_options: Data: 7.47MB + Index: 0.17MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_postmeta: Data: 12.52MB + Index: 6.80MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_posts: Data: 11.45MB + Index: 0.59MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_revslider_css: Data: 0.13MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_revslider_layer_animations: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_revslider_navigations: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_revslider_sliders: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_revslider_slides: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_revslider_static_slides: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_term_relationships: Data: 0.05MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_term_taxonomy: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_termmeta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_terms: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_usermeta: Data: 1.50MB + Index: 0.67MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_users: Data: 0.06MB + Index: 0.05MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_admin_note_actions: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_admin_notes: Data: 0.06MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_category_lookup: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_customer_lookup: Data: 0.08MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_download_log: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_order_coupon_lookup: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_order_product_lookup: Data: 0.19MB + Index: 0.23MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_order_stats: Data: 0.13MB + Index: 0.11MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_order_tax_lookup: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_product_download_directories: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_product_meta_lookup: Data: 0.03MB + Index: 0.09MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_rate_limits: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_reserved_stock: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_tax_rate_classes: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wc_webhooks: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wcpdf_invoice_number: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wfblockediplog: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wfblocks7: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wfconfig: Data: 1.42MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wfcrawlers: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wffilechanges: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wffilemods: Data: 8.52MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wfhits: Data: 2.02MB + Index: 0.25MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wfhoover: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wfissues: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wfknownfilelist: Data: 4.52MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wflivetraffichuman: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wflocs: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wflogins: Data: 0.42MB + Index: 0.16MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wfls_2fa_secrets: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wfls_settings: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wfnotifications: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wfpendingissues: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wfpklist_template_data: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wfreversecache: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wfsnipcache: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.05MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wfstatus: Data: 0.13MB + Index: 0.09MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wftrafficrates: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_gc_activity: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_gc_cards: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_woocommerce_gc_cardsmeta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wpmailsmtp_debug_events: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wpmailsmtp_tasks_meta: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wpml_mails: Data: 18.31MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine MyISAM
wp_wpmm_subscribers: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wt_iew_action_history: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wt_iew_cron: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wt_iew_ftp: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_wt_iew_mapping_template: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_yoast_indexable: Data: 0.27MB + Index: 0.13MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_yoast_indexable_hierarchy: Data: 0.05MB + Index: 0.05MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_yoast_migrations: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.02MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_yoast_primary_term: Data: 0.02MB + Index: 0.03MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_yoast_seo_links: Data: 0.09MB + Index: 0.06MB + Engine InnoDB
wp_yoast_seo_meta: Data: 0.14MB + Index: 0.00MB + Engine InnoDB

### Post Type Counts ###

amn_exact-metrics: 1
attachment: 887
carousels: 7
condition_group: 1
custom_css: 5
customize_changeset: 4
elementor_library: 16
em_reviews: 95
mc4wp-form: 1
nav_menu_item: 51
page: 48
popup_theme: 12
post: 44
postman_sent_mail: 250
product: 86
product_variation: 90
restriction: 1
revision: 696
shop_coupon: 39
shop_order: 834
shop_order_refund: 28
slides: 13
testimonials: 6
wp_global_styles: 1
wpcf7_contact_form: 2

### Security ###

Secure connection (HTTPS): ✔
Hide errors from visitors: ✔

### Active Plugins (23) ###

LayerSlider: by Kreatura Media – 7.5.0
Cache Enabler: by KeyCDN – 1.8.12
CommerceGurus Commercekit: by CommerceGurus – 2.0.4.1
Contact Form 7: by Takayuki Miyoshi – 5.6.3
Cookie Notice & Compliance for GDPR / CCPA: by Hu-manity.co – 2.4.1
Elementor Pro: by Elementor.com – 3.7.3
Elementor: by Elementor.com – 3.7.8
Kirki Customizer Framework: by David Vongries – 4.0.24
Lucas String Replace: by lucasstad – 2.0.5
Mailchimp for WooCommerce: by Mailchimp – 2.7.5
WooCommerce PDF Invoices, Packing Slips, Delivery Notes and Shipping Labels: by WebToffee – 3.0.6
Variation Swatches for WooCommerce: by Woosuite – 2.1.6
WooCommerce Address Validation: by SkyVerge – 2.9.0
WooCommerce Stripe Gateway: by WooCommerce – 6.8.0
WooCommerce Gift Cards: by WooCommerce – 1.10.2 (update to version 1.13.0 is available)
WooCommerce Product Dependencies: by SomewhereWarm – 1.2.7
WooCommerce Table Rate Shipping: by Bolder Elements – 3.6.6
WooCommerce: by Automattic – 6.9.4
Wordfence Security: by Wordfence – 7.7.1
WP Mail Logging: by Wysija – 1.10.4
WP Mail SMTP: by WPForms – 3.6.1
WP Maintenance Mode & Coming Soon: by Themeisle – 2.5.4
WPS Hide Login: by WPServeur
NicolasKulka
wpformation – 1.9.6


### Inactive Plugins (2) ###

Floating Reviews and Testimonials: by WiseLaw – 1.7
Images to WebP: by KubiQ – 2.0

### Dropin Plugins (1) ###

advanced-cache.php: advanced-cache.php

### Settings ###

API Enabled: ✔
Force SSL: –
Currency: GBP (£)
Currency Position: left
Thousand Separator: ,
Decimal Separator: .
Number of Decimals: 2
Taxonomies: Product Types: external (external)
grouped (grouped)
simple (simple)
variable (variable)

Taxonomies: Product Visibility: exclude-from-catalog (exclude-from-catalog)
exclude-from-search (exclude-from-search)
featured (featured)
outofstock (outofstock)
rated-1 (rated-1)
rated-2 (rated-2)
rated-3 (rated-3)
rated-4 (rated-4)
rated-5 (rated-5)

Connected to WooCommerce.com: ✔
Enforce Approved Product Download Directories: –

### WC Pages ###

Shop base: #15746 - /firewood_shop/
Basket: ❌ Page does not contain the [woocommerce_cart] shortcode or the woocommerce/cart block.
Checkout: #12036 - /checkout/
My account: #12037 - /my-account/
Terms and conditions: ❌ Page not set

### Theme ###

Name: Shoptimizer
Version: 2.5.5
Author URL: https://www.commercegurus.com/
Child Theme: ❌ – If you are modifying WooCommerce on a parent theme that you did not build
personally we recommend using a child theme. See: How to create a child theme

WooCommerce Support: ✔

### Templates ###

Overrides: –

### Gift Cards ###

Database Version: 1.10.2
Loopback Test: ✔
Task Queueing Test: ✔

### Admin ###

Enabled Features: activity-panels
analytics
coupons
customer-effort-score-tracks
experimental-products-task
experimental-import-products-task
experimental-fashion-sample-products
experimental-product-tour
shipping-smart-defaults
shipping-setting-tour
homescreen
marketing
mobile-app-banner
navigation
onboarding
onboarding-tasks
remote-inbox-notifications
remote-free-extensions
payment-gateway-suggestions
shipping-label-banner
subscriptions
store-alerts
transient-notices
wc-pay-promotion
wc-pay-welcome-page

Disabled Features: minified-js
new-product-management-experience
settings

Daily Cron: ✔ Next scheduled: 2022-10-12 10:56:33 +01:00
Options: ✔
Notes: 69
Onboarding: completed

### Address Validation ###

Active Provider: Loqate
Configured: ✔
Validate international addresses: Yes
Debug Mode: No
Geocode Addresses: No
Classify Addresses: No
Force Customer to look-up address via Postcode: No

### Action Scheduler ###

Canceled: 3
Oldest: 2022-09-20 14:31:10 +0100
Newest: 2022-10-11 09:32:33 +0100

Complete: 1,018
Oldest: 2022-09-11 09:51:48 +0100
Newest: 2022-10-11 12:01:34 +0100

Pending: 2
Oldest: 2022-10-12 04:30:03 +0100
Newest: 2022-10-12 11:37:07 +0100


### Status report information ###

Generated at: 2022-10-11 12:53:07 +01:00
`
```

Comment: Try switching theme and check

Comment: Issue persists on Storefront theme

Comment: Noway, The default Apply Coupon is an Ajax action - Your "Apply Coupon" is submitting the page and reloads

Comment: I've just double-checked: coupons still don't work on Storefront.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. I'm using a plugin called Lucas String Replace to change various text strings around the site (mainly to switch Americanisms in plugins to British English). I'd set up a rule to replace the word 'coupon' with the word 'voucher' - presumably this was breaking some code somewhere.

Silly error. Posting this answer in case someone else encounters the same issue in future.

Answer (score 1):

I tested with the js console open and if you analyze the respone you get from the server there's this message:

```
Please enter a gift card code that follows the format XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX,
where X can be any letter or number.
```

I don't know where that comes from but it doesn't seem to be default Wc thing (tried searching the string in an empty woocommerce installation)

There must be something with one of your plugin but i don't have any clue of which one it could be. Judging by the list u've pasted i would start from WooCommerce Gift Cards: by WooCommerce – 1.10.2

Comment: That's a different thing: gift cards are purchased that can be bought and are in the format above; coupons are generated in the Woocommerce backend and are entered in a field at the bottom of the checkout page.

Edit: I've already tried deactivating that plugin individually, and all plugins. The issue persisted in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

the coupon form is Elementor's coupon form which is completely detached from the Woocomerce checkout.
Steps to fix - check Elementor template / remove the current coupon form bottom / enable coupon field in Elementor checkout widget

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed your steps and enabled the coupon field in the Elementor checkout widget, but the coupons still do not work. In fact, when you click the 'Apply' button to apply the coupon code, it behaves the same way as pressing 'Place Order' (i.e., prompts you to fill any missing fields, or completes the order).